# How do I create and set the depth of a cube in blender 2.80?

Tags: modeling, mesh

In edit mode I click on add cube, I click on the screen to set the location of the 3d cursor. Then I click and drag to create a rectangle shaped cube.

But how do I set the depth to be the same as one of the other sides ? Or how do I define the depth at all?

I am not seeing any properties relating to the size of the cube being created. The cube created for me is very thin rectangle like a plank of laminate flooring and I cant work out how to make it thicker and square like a wooden post.

Creating a square cube or post seems such a basic thing and yet it stumps me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the *Edit Mode* "*Add Cube*" tool, you should get handles that you can use to modify your cube **visually**:

After creating the cube (by dragging the left mouse button), orbit around the cube by holding down the <kbd>MMB</kbd> middle mouse button, then just grab a face and pull it in the desired direction. I'm not aware of a way to use these handles with exact numbers.

[image]

---

However, if you want to create a new cube and set its dimensions, I suggest adding it in *Object Mode* with *Add > Mesh > Cube*. In the "number" panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) you will be able to set its dimensions precisely.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.I found that as well as addcube on the left hand menu there is also an add menu with a cube at the top of the pane in edit mode, though that only allows you to set 1 dimension, but it does create a cube ! So I think its is only the object mode version that lets you set all 3 dimensions explicitly. So from your answer and from what I have found using it, I think that the edit mode add cube tool in the left hand  tools panel cant  currently create a square cube !

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. To be able to set dimensions precisely you should use Object Mode's number panel. With the cube tool in edit mode you can obtain any proportions, but only visually. Another thing I didn't mention is that in any mode you can add a unit cube (Add > Cube) then do Scale constrained to each axis separately, and type in the amount (e.g. *"S", "X", "1.26", "Enter"*).  My suggestion is: never use the Edit Mode Cube tool (unless you need it to bridge pieces in an approximate way, or set a simulation domain, or something like that).